# Pseudo element :before rendering differently in Windows 8 and Ubuntu

Tags: html, css

I am using `Entypo` web font to create buttons with icons. In short I do the following to add the icon to the button:

```
.button {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    padding: 10px 18px;
    background-color: gray; 
}

.with-icon:before {
    content: '\1F50D';
    font-size: 32px;
    width: 40px;
    display: block;
    top: 8px;
    left: 0;
    text-align: center;     
    position: absolute;
    font-family: 'Entypo';
    font-weight: normal;
    color: white;
}
```

The simple HTML:

```
<a href="" class="button with-icon">Button</a>
```

Everything was going fine while trying this on Ubuntu (Chrome, Firefox and Opera) but when I decided to test everything on Windows (Chrome, Firefox and IE) a strange error ocurred. It's easily noticed:

Ubuntu:

[image: Ubuntu]

Windows:

[image: Windows]

The icon on Windows is placed lower than when testing on Ubuntu. I tried leaving the `:before` class without the `top` attribute, it works on Ubuntu (the icon is placed in the middle) and on Windows the icon is placed even lower.

What may be ocurring?

(Sorry for my english)

Comment: Can you check with a symbol not from a webfont? I vaguely recall there may be baseline issues.

Comment: I tried putting a letter instead of the symbol and changing the font to a simple sans-serif and it works fine in both systems. Is there anything that can be done?

Comment: I assume you have the font in the usual four formats (woff, eot, svg, ttf)? As a voodoo stab in the dark, I'd try pushing the svg font through a svg-to-ttf converter like [Free Font Converter](http://www.freefontconverter.com/) and that TTF through a [@fontface generator](http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fontface/generator).

Comment: Are you using the kit from fontsquirrel? I might have to take a deeper look a tthe files to make a more educated guess.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the top style twice. Maybe this is already the error?

```
top: 2px;
display: block;
top: 8px;
```

If not, could you provide a [Fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net) with all the CSS needed?